# Hadoop client node installation

Tags: hadoop

I have 12 node cluster. Its Hardware information are :

**NameNode :** CPU Core i3 2.7 Ghz | 8GB RAM | 500 GB HDD

**DataNode :** CPU Core i3 2.7 Ghz | 2GB RAM | 500 GB HDD

I have installed the hadoop 2.7.2. I am using normal hadoop installation process on ubuntu and it work fine. But I want to add client machine.and I have no such clue that how to add client machine.

**Question :**

1. Installing process of Client machine. ?
2. How to run any script of pig/hive on that client machine ?

Comment: Please limit your posts to one question. The information you are asking for is quite broad

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Client should have same copy of Hadoop Distribution and configuration which is present at Namenode then Only Client will come to know on which node Job tracker/Resourcemanager is running, and IP of Namenode to access HDFS data.

Also you need to update `/etc/hosts` of client machine with IP addresses and hostnames of namenode and datanode.
Note that, you shouldn’t start any hadoop service on client machine.

Steps to follow on client machine:

- create an user account on the cluster, say `user1`
- create an account on client machine with the same name: `user1`
- configure client machine to access the cluster machines (ssh w\out passphrase i.e, password less login)
- copy/get a hadoop distribution same as cluster to client machine and extract it to `/home/user1/hadoop-2.x.x`
- copy(or Edit) the hadoop configuration files (*-site.xml) from Namenode of the cluster - from this client will know where the Namenode/resourcemanager is running.
- Set environment variables: `JAVA_HOME`, `HADOOP_HOME` (`/home/user1/hadoop-2.x.x`)
- Set hadoop bin to your path: `export PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$PATH`

test it out: `hadoop fs -ls /` which should list the root directory of the cluster hdfs.

you may face some issues like privileges, may need to set JAVA_HOME places like `conf/hadoop-env.sh` on client machine. update/comment any error you get.

**Answers to more questions from comments:**

1. *How to load data from client node to hdfs ?* - Just run `hadoop fs` commands from client machine: `hadoop fs -put /home/user1/data/* /user/user1/data` - you can also write shell-scripts that would run these command(s) if you need to run them many times.
2. *Why I am installing hadoop on the client if we only use `ssh` to connect remotely to the master node ?*

   - because client need to communicate with cluster, and need to know
     where cluster nodes are.
   - client will be running hadoop jobs
     like hadoop fs commands, hive queries, hadoop jar commnads, spark
     jobs, developing mapreduce jobs etc for which client will need
     hadoop binaries on client node.
   - Basically you are not only using the `ssh` to
     connect, but you are performing some operations on hadoop cluster from
     client node so you would need hadoop binaries.
   - `ssh` is used by
     hadoop binaries on client node, when you run such operations like `hadoop fs
     -ls/`  from client node to cluster. (remember adding `$HADOOP_HOME/bin` to `PATH` as part of installation process above)
   - when you are saying "we only use `ssh`" - that sounds to me like when you want to make changes/access hadoop configuration files from cluster you are connecting using `ssh` to cluster nodes - you do this as part of administrative work but when you need to run hadoop commands/jobs against cluster from client node you dont need to `ssh` manually - hadoop installation on client node will take care of it.
   - with out hadoop instalations how can you run hadoop commands/jobs/queries from client node to cluster?

   *3. should user name 'user1' must be same ? what if it is different ?* - it will work. you can install hadoop on client node under group user say: `qa` or `dev`, and all users on client node as sudo under that group. than when `user1` on client node need to run any hadoop job on cluster: `user1` should be able to `sudo -i -u qa` and then run hadoop command from it.

Comment: ok it work fine. But 1. How to load data from client node to hdfs ?

Comment: 2. Why I am installing hadoop on the client if we only use ssh to connect remotely to the master node ?

Comment: 3. should user name 'user1' must be same ? what if it is different ?

Comment: see updated answer: I think your original two questions are being answered. please accept this as an answer if this has helped you. also let me know if you have further questions. or you can create separate post for them.